# Blender refuses to start

Tags: linux, drivers, blender, display-driver

I'm trying to run Blender under Linux, but I'm unable to do that, whenever I try I get some errors. I'm using Kubuntu 12.04 with KDE 4.11.1.

This is my video card:

```
~$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV610/M74 [Mobility Radeon HD 2400 XT]
```

I used to have installed the `fglrx` proprietary Catalyst drivers, but lately they gave me some system-wide problems and I had to revert to the open source Mesa drivers (I don't think that these details are important, but just in case, [the whole story is here](https://superuser.com/q/643089/170331)).
Whit the `fglrx` drivers Blender was running fine, but now, whenever I try to start it, I get this error message (some parts are in italian, but I think that they are easily understandable):

```
~$ blender
connect failed: No such file or directory
Writing: /tmp/blender.crash.txt
Errore di segmentazione (core dump creato)
```

The content of `/tmp/blender.crash.txt` is as follows:

```
# Blender 2.68 (sub 5), Revision: 60150

# backtrace
/usr/lib/blender/blender() [0x877a41f]
[0xb7756400]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libLLVM-3.0.so.1(_ZN4llvm3ARM8SPRClassC1Ev+0x15) [0xa8f4a9d5]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libLLVM-3.0.so.1(+0x25ca48) [0xa8eefa48]
/lib/ld-linux.so.2(+0xeeab) [0xb7765eab]
/lib/ld-linux.so.2(+0xef94) [0xb7765f94]
/lib/ld-linux.so.2(+0x12fa6) [0xb7769fa6]
/lib/ld-linux.so.2(+0xeccf) [0xb7765ccf]
/lib/ld-linux.so.2(+0x127f4) [0xb77697f4]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2(+0xbe9) [0xb4ff9be9]
/lib/ld-linux.so.2(+0xeccf) [0xb7765ccf]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2(+0x133a) [0xb4ffa33a]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2(dlopen+0x47) [0xb4ff9c97]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1(+0x3cbf0) [0xb7717bf0]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1(+0x4079d) [0xb771b79d]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1(+0x1a3aa) [0xb76f53aa]
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1(glXQueryVersion+0x2e) [0xb76f0cee]
/usr/lib/blender/blender(_ZN15GHOST_WindowX11C1EP15GHOST_SystemX11P9_XDisplayRK10STR_Stringiijj18GHOST_TWindowStatei25GHOST_TDrawingContextTypebbt+0x11c) [0x8f54aec]
/usr/lib/blender/blender(_ZN15GHOST_SystemX1112createWindowERK10STR_Stringiijj18GHOST_TWindowState25GHOST_TDrawingContextTypebbti+0xd7) [0x8f4f4a7]
/usr/lib/blender/blender(GHOST_CreateWindow+0xb6) [0x8f4cf86]
/usr/lib/blender/blender(wm_window_add_ghostwindows+0x205) [0x8799be5]
/usr/lib/blender/blender(WM_check+0x50) [0x877b670]
/usr/lib/blender/blender(wm_homefile_read+0x111) [0x87859f1]
/usr/lib/blender/blender(WM_init+0xd2) [0x8787872]
/usr/lib/blender/blender(main+0xe6e) [0x873848e]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0xb4e694d3]
/usr/lib/blender/blender() [0x8778a99]
```

The only thing that I can guess from this report is that the mesa drivers are somewhat involved, as I already suspected, but I don't have a clue on what I need to do to try to solve the issue.

Comment: Use the [Ubuntu package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=blender) and not the installer from the blender site.

Comment: I haven't used the package from the blender site, it's from this repo https://launchpad.net/~irie/+archive/blender and worked fine until I had to disable `fglrx`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using debian-based distro, try to install `firmware-linux-nonfree` package to make opensource drivers work properly with direct rendering.

Ps. don't forget to reboot system after installing firmware package.